# Não estou conseguindo acessar o MySQL pelo PHP

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Estou com o seguinte problema, eu utilizo o Ubunto e instalei o mariadb, e quando eu tento acessar o mysql com:

```
mysql -u root
```

Aparece o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

E então consigo acessa-lo apenas utilizando o:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

E agora, quando tento fazer:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'php_alura');
```

Não acontece nada, e minha página nem renderiza.

Alguém pode me ajuda?

**Atualização:**

Uma **observação** importante é que só consigo acessar o mysql pelo bach utilizando a permissão **sudo**, ou seja com:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

Eu consigo ter acesso.

Comment: Qual o código que está a utilizar para aceder aos dados  e mostrar os mesmos? Qual o código da página que não renderiza?

Comment: Então amigo, o código de conexão é o seguinte: `$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'php_alura');` Porém eu eu dei um restart no apache e agora está renderizando as páginas, porem não consigo fazer a conexão com o mysql. **OBS:** Eu só consigo mexer no mysql pelo painel usando a permissão de **sudo**, acredito que tenha alguma relação, mas não sei como resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está apenas fazendo a conexão ou está executando uma query também ?

O código abaixo executa a conexão e faz a verificação se houve erro, em caso de erro irá mostrar a mensagem de erro e finalizar, em caso de haver sucesso na conexão mostrará a mensagem de sucesso e depois fechará a conexão com a base de dados.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "BASE");
if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Falha ao conectar-se com o banco de dados MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
echo "Sucesso: Sucesso ao conectar-se com a base de dados MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
mysqli_close($link);
```

**Atualização**

Siga os passos na ordem:
1 - finalize o mysql:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

2 - Inicie-o no modo de segurança:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

3 - Este será um comando contínuo até o processo terminar, então abra outra janela de shell / terminal e faça o login sem uma senha como root:

```
mysql -u root
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NOVASENHA';
```

Altere NOVASENHA por uma senha desejada e inicie o MySQL

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Comment: Me retornou:

Error: Falha ao conectar-se com o banco de dados MySQL. Debugging errno: 1698 Debugging error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: Então amigo, eu tentei fazer o comando: 

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop ` 

Porem voltou o seguinte

`sudo: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: comando não encontrado` 

Então dei uma pesquisada e tentei fazer o seguinte:

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Que retornou o seguinte:

`[ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.`

Então tentei fazer o segundo comando que me passou e retornou isso:
`170801 13:26:23 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
170801 13:26:23 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists`

Comment: Já que você consegue acessar o MySQL pelo terminal usando sudo, siga os passou dessa print : http://imageshack.com/a/img922/2082/60pALx.png

Comment: Depois é só configurar no php para se conectar sem senha

Comment: Deve ficar assim, certo? http://imageshack.com/a/img923/7910/EmVqKQ.png

Comment: Porem o seu código ainda aparece: `Error: Falha ao conectar-se com o banco de dados MySQL. Debugging errno: 1698 Debugging error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' `

Comment: Sim, tem que trocar os valores, HOST, USUARIO, SENHA e BASE ficando assim $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "php_alura");

Comment: mas está igual `$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "php_alura");`

Comment: Agora fica um pouco difícil de poder ajudar, pois estou no trabalho, aqui não consigo ver a print que você colocou no comentário, se alguém poder ajudar. se não só amanha cedo quando eu chegar em casa

Comment: Tudo bem cara, mas o print era apenas eu mostrando que fiz exatamente o que pediu ` | root | mysql_native_password | ` (tabela no mysql)

Comment: Isso, é pra ficar desse jeito da print mesmo. Tente reinstalar o mysql, removendo ele primeiro por completo

Comment: Muito Obrigado amigo!!! Eu não havia reiniciado o computador e agora que testei o que me pediu funcionou!!!!! (Não precisei re instalar) Muito obrigado mesmo!!!!